# running an animation on a thread android

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

i am trying to run a  simple button animation when the game is over 
i have the following classes: 
GameView  
GameThread

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
boolean gameover;GameThread gamethread;

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    gameover=true;


    getHolder().addCallback(this); // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events

    setFocusable(true);// make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events

}






@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

    Log.d("TAG", "surface changed");
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


            gamethread=new GameThread(getHolder(),this);
            gamethread.setrunning(true);
            gamethread.start();






}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry=true;
    Log.d("TAG", "Surface destroyed entered");



    while(retry){
    try {
        gamethread.setrunning(false);
        gamethread.join();
        gamethread=null;
        Log.d("tag","thread is destroyed" );
        if(gamethread==null){
            Log.d("tag","thread is destroyed and null" );

        }
        retry=false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }//end while
}//end method




public void update(){



    if(gameover){


        Button gameover_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gameover);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.gameoveranimation);
        gameover_button.startAnimation(animation);

}

}//end update`
```

```
public class GameThread extends Thread  {
// desired fps


private boolean running;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceholder;
private GameView gameview;

public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GameView gameview){
    this.gameview=gameview;
    this.surfaceholder=surfaceHolder; //we need the surfaceholder since we need to lock surface before drawing

}
public void setrunning(boolean running){

    this.running=running;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    super.run();
    Canvas canvas;




        while(running){

        canvas=null;


        canvas = this.surfaceholder.lockCanvas();
        synchronized (surfaceholder) {
            if(canvas!=null){
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            this.gameview.Draw1(canvas);

            this.gameview.update();

            }//end if







            }
        }

        }finally{//in case of an exception
            if(canvas!=null){
            surfaceholder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
                }//end finally
                        }//end loop


                        }//end run

}

<br>
```

everything works fine except the animation in the update method in the gameview class 
the animation runs fine in the oncreate method
i know that my  problem is  related to thread but i don't know much about them 
thx in advance

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue is that you need to call update on the UI thread, then you can use this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.gameview.update();
    }
});
```

Also, it looks like you are looking for your game-over button as a child of your surface view. If that is not correct, you can find the view relative to the parent activity.

```
Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
Button gameover_button = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.gameover);
```

Comment: just one thing in the last sentences i can't access the getActivity() in the gameview class

Comment: You're right, sorry, I've updated my answer. You can get a View's Context, and presumably for your gameview that Context will always be an Activity. (I suppose you could do "if (context instanceof Activity)" to be really safe.)